# How to document asynchronous results, exceptions?

Tags: asynchronous, javadoc

Javadoc has clear rules for documenting the return value and exceptions thrown by a method. But what are we supposed to do for methods that return/throw from within an asynchronous response such as [CompletionStage](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CompletionStage.html) or [Future](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Future.html)?

If I use `@throws` to document exceptions that are thrown asynchronously, the IDE complains that the method doesn't throw the exceptions (directly). And it is right, the method does not.

If I document the long list of exceptions that are thrown asynchronously in the `@return` section the resulting documentation is difficult to read.

What is the best practice for this situation? If possible, please reference established libraries as examples.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For what it's worth, I'm currently using the following syntax but I don't think it is an established best practice:

```
/**
 * @param symbol the name of a stock ticker
 * @return the price of the ticker
 * <br> {@code @throws NullPointerException} if {@code symbol} is null
 * <br> {@code @throws IOException} if an I/O error occurs
 */
public CompletionStage<BigDecimal> getPrice(String symbol);
```

My guidelines are as follows:

- Throw all exceptions asynchronously, even for instant failures like argument preconditions. This allows clients to centralize error handling in one place.
- Document exceptions under the `@return` using the same `@throws` syntax that is familiar to developers.

The result looks quite decent.